# Redactor editor change image tag when upload

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, redactor

When Uploading a image through Redactor

Redactor will generate `<img src="blablabla.png"/>` tag

What if I want the tag is like:

```
<img class="myClass" src="blablabla.png"/>
```

How to do this?

I have viewed all the API and Callback but I didn't find any method to implement this.

Comment: It seems a quite specific requirement, can ppl assign classes to images through the editor?

Comment: @Filype ya quite specific.

But I think it can easily for user to change the image tag template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use the [imageUploadCallback](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/#api-imageUploadCallback).

This callback is triggered on successful image upload and the image DOM element is there for you to manipulate.

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    imageUploadCallback: function(image, json)
    {
        // image = this is DOM element of image
        // json = for example: { "filelink": "/images/img.jpg" }
    }
});
```

Comment: I thinking of this, and also using `blurCallback` to parse all the <img/> tag and addClass to them, just too busy on this. Hope I can easily change the redactor image tag template.

Comment: Even the ones that were not uploaded through redactor?

Comment: Filype is correct your best option is to use `imageUploadCallback` and `dropCallback` to `addClass` to image like so `image.addClass('myClass');` the returned image is already a jQuery object