# How can I add class to uploaded image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redactor, redactor.js

I'm using redactorjs editor via https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails gem. How can I add `class="img-responsive"` to all images uploaded with this editor?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the uploaded image DOM, using redactor's callback.

The following answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865048/redactor-editor-change-image-tag-when-upload). More about `imageUploadCallback` is [here](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/image/#callback-imageUploadCallback).

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    imageUploadCallback: function(image, json)
    {
        // image = this is DOM element of image, add the 'img
        $(image).addClass("img-responsive");    
    } 
});
```